# Скрипт javascript

Tags: javascript

Что это за скрипт -

```
 var timers=new Array();
 function hidee(menuID)
 {
    var currentmenu = document.getElementById("menu"+menuID);
    currentmenu.style.display = 'none';
 }
  function menuhide(menuID)
  {

    timers[menuID]=setTimeout ('hidee('+menuID+')',400);
  }

  function menushow(menuID)
  {
      if(timers[menuID])
      clearTimeout (timers[menuID]);

    var currentmenu = document.getElementById("menu"+menuID);
    currentmenu.style.display = 'block';
  }
```

Comment: Код показывает и скрывает (с задержской 0.4 с.) элементы меню

Answer (score 2):

В данном контексте код ровным счетом не делает нифига. Тут просто инициализация функций. А если бы и делал, то показывал и скрывал элементы меню. Если к этому коду прилагается html, то не поленитесь выложить